# $(build_executable) producing shared object

Tags: android-ndk

I'm trying to create an native executable for android and it keeps crashing.  testing the file with readelf and objdump revivals that the file is considered to be an shared object file. 
I'm using the r8e and compiling with ndk-build

test.c:

```
int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC FILES := test.c
LOCAL_MODULE := test

include(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

--

Setting the app_platform to android-9  results in the creation of an executable file ( and no crashes).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying arguments `int args` and `char *argv[]` for your main() method? Also, where are you trying to run it?

Comment: yes, and I'm running it on Samsung Galaxy S running CyanogenMod 9

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this bug... I had a project that compiled perfectly with ndk-r8, but when I switched to ndk-8e my executable did not build properly anymore.

I reported it here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55769

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I got from google:

This is normal.
By default, when targetting API level 17 or higher, "Position Independent Executables" (a.k.a. PIE) are generated by the BUILD_EXECUTABLE rule.

These are *executable binaries*, but they are only supported on Android 4.1 or higher. See [1] for more details.

If you really don't want these (e.g. because you want your program to run on previous releases of the platform), you have two choices:

- Target a lower API level.
- Use 'APP_PIE := false' in your Application.mk